# Unable to turn off Tokenized Sending

Tags: marketing-cloud, administration

For testing purposes i enabled Tokenized Sending in my Marketing Cloud Account. I'm not able to change it back to 'None'. When i change and save, i get the error "There was an error saving the Tokenized Sending settings"

And in the 'Apply Settings To Account'  |   "The settings were not applied due to one or more failed tests". It does not show any test names with this.

Comment: I would recommend raising a case for Support to disable Tokenized Sending.

Answer (score 1):

Please raise a support case with SFMC Support team. They should be able to turn this off if you can't.